# Drupal: Rules executing custom PHP don't work

Tags: php, drupal-6, drupal-modules, rules

I installed the module Rules and created a rule: when content is saved, `echo 1+1;` is executed.
Nothing happens when I create a new content and save it.

- PHP filter is enabled
- Rules module is enabled
- All other conditions and actions work fine
- It works fine on local server

Is there anything wrong in the remote server (Fedora 9, PHP 5.2.9)?
Is there anything that needs to be enabled in order to allow Rules to execute custom PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't see the output because after content is saved it echo 1+1 and immediately it redirect to the view page of newly created content. try exit(); after echo in code to see if it gives output or not.

Comment: Dipesh, maybe you are right. I discovered that even if it doesn't show the risult of echo 1+1, using some code to write into a text file works fine. So I think it works, the problem is just the echo and probably happens what you said.